# How to exclude specific column in export html table data using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, export

I've coded three types of export table data facilities i.e. PNG, XLS and WORD. In my HTML table I want to exclude from exporting the last column which has options edit & delete.And also XLS and WORD  row which I want to include.

```
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Export Table Data</button>
        <ul class='id_ul'>
            <li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/xls.png' width='24px'> XLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'doc',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/word.png' width='24px'> Word</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'png',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/png.png' width='24px'> PNG</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I'd tried to write a function on onClick to do this but doesn't help.

Comment: is there any solution to hide specific column where <th> name like 'options'?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the column number in `ignoreColumn` syntax as displaying in the following exapmle

```
$('#table_report').tableExport({ type: 'excel',escape:'false',ignoreColumn: [6]});
```

Answer (score 0):

onclick you should call a function [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

> element.onclick = functionRef;

`where functionRef is a function - often a name of a function declared elsewhere or a function expression.`

Do This=>

HTML:

```
 <li><a href="#" onClick ="export('excel','false')"> <img src='icons/xls.png' width='24px'> XLS</a></li>
```

Js:

```
function export(expotype,toescape){
"$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:expotype,escape:toescape});
}
```

Comment: The plugin which i'm using <script src="jquery-tableexport/tableExport.js"></script> has following options                                     separator: ',',
      ignoreColumn: [1,4],
      tableName:'yourTableName',
      type:'csv',
      pdfFontSize:7,
      pdfLeftMargin:2,
      escape:'true',
      htmlContent:'true',
      consoleLog:'false'                                 ,the ignoreColumn:[1,4] doesn't work. For that, is there any solution to hide specific row where <th> name is 'options'?